# Angular 2 - create multiable components with the same service instance

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, angular2-components

**Calling Components:**

```
<some-component></some-component>
<some-component></some-component>
```

**Component:**

```
@Component ({
  selector : 'some-component',
})

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor (private someService : SomeService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.someService.register();
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService{
   private targets: Array;
    constructor (private http: Http) {}

    register(){
     this.targets.push('x');
     getData();
    }   

    getData(){
      console.log(targets);
      let params = this.targets.join(); // 'x,x'
      return this.http.get(params);
    }
}
```

**console:**

```
['x']
['x','x']
// what I need to do to whit until the last one and make the get request.
```

Hello as you can see in my code I need to call a component many times with the same injected service and not to repeat the get request just making the Get request once for all the components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach**

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component ({
  selector : 'some-component',
})

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() isLast = false;

    constructor (private someService : SomeService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.someService.register();
      if (this.isLast) {
        this.someService.getData();
      }
    }
}
```

Delete the `this.getData()` inside your service's register()

Then in the template where you drop SomeComponents in

```
<some-component></some-component>
<some-component></some-component>
<some-component [isLast]='true'></some-component>
```

**Second approach**

```
@Component ({
  selector : 'some-component',
})

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor (private someService : SomeService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.someService.register();
    }
}
```

Delete the `this.getData()` inside your service's `register()`

Then inside the component class of the template where you insert your `SomeComponent`s, let's say this parent component is `AppComponent`

```
.
.
.
export class AppComponent ... {

  constructor (private someService : SomeService) {}

  // import AfterViewInit from angular core package
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      this.someService.getData();
  }
}
```

Comment: but I want to push value in the register array in for every component this flag will just push for first call @Dummy

Comment: this there any another way to solve that without flag it on the component input??
it's really good idea but i need to solve this without flag it in the component @Dummy